# how to detect alt-text of each image in a div and do an if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to ask you how it is possible to get the `alt` attr of each image in a div and depending on the value do an if-statement:

An example:

```
<div id="images">
  <img src="image1" alt="img1">
  <img src="image1" alt="img1">
  <img src="image2" alt="img2">
  <img src="image1" alt="img1">
  <img src="image3" alt="img3">
</div>
```

and I would like to get `$('#images');` grab every `<img>` and then do:

```
if(altofimage == 'img1')  { /* do something */ };
if(altofimage == 'img2')  { /* do something other */ };
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#images img").each(function(){
   if($(this).attr('alt') == 'img1') { /* do something*/ }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#images img").each(function() {
    switch (this.alt) {
    case "img1":
        /* do something */
        break;
    case "img2":
        /* do something else */
        break;
    ...
    default: 
        /* do default thing */
    }
});
```